# How to forward port 8080 from a distant server to the client from the client using a tunnel ssh?

Tags: ssh, docker, port, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have installed GitLab in docker on a distant machine. I would now like to forward the port 8080 from this distant machine to my local port 8080.

On the distant machine:

```sh
sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.example.com --publish 443:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

On my local machine:

```sh
ssh -N -o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes" -R 8080:localhost:8080 someuser@the-distant-server -vvv
```

I get the following error:

```
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/someuser/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 8080, connect localhost:8080
Error: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 8080
```

And indeed, in the `/var/log/auth.log`, I get the following error:

```
Jul  9 16:51:42 distant-server sshd[2723782]: Accepted publickey for someuser from 192.168.200.182 port 44850 ssh2: RSA SHA256:
Jul  9 16:51:42 distant-server sshd[2723782]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user someuser by (uid=0)
Jul  9 16:51:42 distant-server systemd-logind[1083]: New session 116923 of user someuser.
Jul  9 16:51:42 distant-server systemd[2723795]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user someuser by (uid=0)
Jul  9 16:51:43 distant-server sshd[2723812]: error: bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use
Jul  9 16:51:43 distant-server sshd[2723812]: error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8080
Jul  9 16:51:43 distant-server sshd[2723782]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user someuser
Jul  9 16:51:43 distant-server systemd-logind[1083]: Session 116923 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul  9 16:51:43 distant-server systemd-logind[1083]: Removed session 116923.
```

It tells me `bind [127.0.0.1]:8080: Address already in use`.

1. I don't understand how I can listen to port 8080 from the distant machine if no process can write to it. I think I have a misunderstanding of how ports/listening/writing/ssh work here.
2. How can I fix the `ssh` command to make this tunnel work and access the GitLab instance on my `127.0.0.1:8080`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use the ssh switch `-L` instead of `-R`.

Explanation: On the distant machine, you open a docker container which publishes the port 8080. This means in detail, that the docker host opens up a `LISTEN` socket and wait for incoming connections.

There are two types of port forwardings: -L and -R:

- `-L` opens up a listen socket on your local machine and forwards this incoming connection through the ssh tunnel, and opens a connection on the remote host to the specified address (`localhost:8080` in this case, which is exactly what you want)
- `-R` works the other way around: it waits for incoming connections on the remote machine, and forwards it to the local host. This fails of course because you already have a listen socket sitting on this address (the docker container!)

You always have to think about who is initiating the connection. The Gitlab instance is probably accessible via a browser, which means that your **local** browser tries to open the connection, therefore you must have the listen socket available locally.

Comment: It is the first time I read about `LISTEN` sockets when looking for explanations on ssh tunnels. It made everything much more clear.

Comment: you definitely should take a look at TCP networking basics. No wonder that you misunderstood the ssh tunnel options...